# Modify current culture?

Tags: c#, .net

```
 CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");

        culture.DateTimeFormat.DateSeparator = "/";
        culture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "dd/MM/yyyy";

        //dekadikoi arithmoi
        culture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;
```

As it is required to work that way everywhere! The problem is that doing `new CultureInfo("en-US");`  all other computer-specific settings are omited...
Is there a way to copy the CurrentCulture?
I tried to modify currentculture but i got read only error...

Comment: You can't modify CultureInfo.CurrentCulture property because it is readonly and it has only "Get" method.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
CultureInfo culture = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Clone();

culture.DateTimeFormat.DateSeparator = "/";
culture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "dd/MM/yyyy";

//dekadikoi arithmoi
culture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;
```

You may wish to use:

```
CultureInfo culture = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.Clone();
```

instead.

Answer (score 3):

Just change one line:

```
CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
```

Answer (score 1):

what about this : 
`CultureInfo culture=CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;`

Answer (score 1):

Just take a copy of the [CurrentCulture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture.aspx) class and modifiy it as you see fit. If you do need to change the CultureInfo of the thread itself (rather than using a copy) you need to give your code a security permission and set the `ControlThread` property to true. (see link for example)

Answer (score 0):

Following on [Jon Hanna](https://stackoverflow.com/users/400547/jon-hanna)'s solution I would suggest starting on a specific culture, as the CurrentCulture can be set to anything.

```
public static CultureInfo GetCustomCulture(string baseCulture = "en-ZA", char numberDecimalSeperator = '.', char listSeperator = ',') {
    var culture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(baseCulture).Clone();

    culture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = numberDecimalSeperator + "";
    culture.TextInfo.ListSeparator = listSeperator + "";

    return culture;
}
```

And then add this line to the beginning of `Program.cs`

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = GetCustomCulture();
```

Comment: That the current culture can be set to anything is precisely the reason for starting with the current culture. This will change all the settings that are intended to remain the same as the current culture.

Comment: @JonHanna, I noticed that you're cloning the culture in your solution. Is that what you're referring to? It didn't really matter in the case where I had to use this culture since we don't use the original settings, but it's still a good catch. Thank you!