# System.FormatException : Input string was not in a correct format ,on converting string to decimal.

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, decimal, formatexception

I have a little problem with ASP.NET and C#. This is my error code:

> An exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in >user code
>
> Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(this.IsPostBack == false)
    {
        Currency.Items.Add(new ListItem("Euro", "0.85"));
        Currency.Items.Add(new ListItem("Yen", "11.30"));
        Currency.Items.Add(new ListItem("PLN", "4.20"));
        Currency.Items.Add(new ListItem("GBP", "5.62"));
    }
}

protected void Convert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    decimal oldAmount;
    bool succes = Decimal.TryParse(TextBox.Value, out oldAmount);

    if(succes)
    {
        ListItem item = Currency.Items[Currency.SelectedIndex];
        decimal newAmount = oldAmount * decimal.Parse(item.Value);
        Result.InnerText = "Result: " + newAmount;
    }

}
```

I tried Decimal.Parse, Decimal.TryParse and other strange combinations. Now I'm sure that issue is with strings and parsing them to decimal. When I created String variable - there was that same error while parsing. So can someone tell me what to do to be able to convert String to decimal?

Comment: TextBox.value is wrong. YourTextBoxID.Text is correct.

Comment: Did you try debugging?

Comment: Nope, TextBox is my id since im using html controlls.

Comment: Jakob Christensen - yes, and I cant see anything strange. When app is on line decimal newAmount ... it throws error beacuse string is in wrong format but I don't know why.

Comment: What does the string for `item.Value` look like on the `decimal newAmount =` line?

Comment: "0.85". The problem was with my culture settings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using "0,85" instead of "0.85". I think you can use the dot decimal if you change culture.
Here is some more information:
[How to change symbol for decimal point in double.ToString()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3135569/how-to-change-symbol-for-decimal-point-in-double-tostring)

Answer (score 2):

Please try with the below code snippet.

```
CultureInfo info = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("es-ES");
string storedValue = "3,85";
decimal oldAmount;
bool succes = Decimal.TryParse(storedValue, NumberStyles.Any, info, out oldAmount);
```

Comment: The problem is not with TextBox - Im using html controls so TextBox as ID works just fine. The problem is in Decimal.Parse(SomeString).

Comment: please provide your textbox's value.

Comment: I don't use textbox. On this page I was using  <input type="text" id="TextBox" runat="server" />. Anyway - Sn1ckers  help me with the issue - problem was in my culture sign. Instead of 0.85 i should use 0,85.

Answer (score 0):

Use TextBox.Text instead:

```
bool succes = Decimal.TryParse(TextBox.Text, out oldAmount);
```

Answer (score 0):

TextBox.value is wrong. YourTextBox.Text is correct...!

```
bool success = Decimal.TryParse(TextBox.Text, out oldAmount);
```

Comment: Same answer is already provided by '@David Brossard' before 3 minutes.