# C# Exception thrown: 'System.FormatException' in mscorlib.dll

Tags: c#

Exception thrown: `System.FormatException` in `mscorlib.dll`

> {"Input string was not in a correct format."}

I have been at this all day. Please help! Those above were the error messages btw. I am a bit new to C# so I could use a bit more detailed answers (I don't get the jargon so well)

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    double a, b, d, f, g, t;
    string z;
    int c;


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {

    }



    private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        a = Convert.ToDouble(textBox18.Text);
        z = Convert.ToString(comboBox1);
        d = Convert.ToDouble(checkBox1);
        f = Convert.ToDouble(textBox13.Text);
        g = Convert.ToDouble(textBox14.Text);
        t = Convert.ToDouble(textBox19.Text);


        if (z == "a")
        {
            textBox15.Text = Convert.ToString(a * g * d * t);
        }
        else if (z == "b")
        {
            textBox15.Text = Convert.ToString(c);
        }
    }
```

Comment: One of your textbox#.Text might be null or empty

Comment: Possible duplicate of [System.FormatException : Input string was not in a correct format ,on converting string to decimal.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23130554/system-formatexception-input-string-was-not-in-a-correct-format-on-converting)

Comment: from combo box if u need to fetch value do this comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString() , see for  checkbox too . they hav properties so use that to fetch value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These could be the possible issues,

the given input may not be in those format which can be converted to double

```
a = Convert.ToDouble(textBox18.Text);
    z = Convert.ToString(comboBox1.SelectedValue);
    d = Convert.ToDouble(checkBox1.Checked);
    f = Convert.ToDouble(textBox13.Text);
    g = Convert.ToDouble(textBox14.Text);
    t = Convert.ToDouble(textBox19.Text);
```

or may be it should be something like

```
    z = Convert.ToString(comboBox1.SelectedValue);
   d = Convert.ToDouble(checkBox1.Checked);
```

Comment: The given input for all the textBoxes are numbers while the given input for the combobox is letters.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take values from Controls instead of parsing the control itself,

like --> for combobox it should be `comboBox.SelectedValue`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this line :

```
  textBox15.Text = Convert.ToString(a * g * d * t);
```

because you are multiplying the d with other values and d contain different type of value as checkbox1 does not return right value

So first you should get the value of check box in right format like :

```
d= Convert.ToDouble(comboBox.SelectedValue)
```

Comment: you can find more detail about error in this link :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12269254/how-to-resolve-input-string-was-not-in-a-correct-format-error