# Filtering a double value

Tags: vb.net, filtering

Windows 11

I would like to filter double values.

[image]

[image]

```
1. testo = text
2. numerico = numeric
3. valuta = currency
```

I can filter Strings

```
Dim srchStr As String = Me.TextBox1.text
Dim strFilter As String = "MyCol1 LIKE '*" & srchStr.Replace("'", "''") & "*'"
dv.RowFilter = strFilter
```

I can filter Integers

```
Dim srchStr As String = Me.TextBox1.Text
Dim id As Integer

If Integer.TryParse(srchStr, id) Then
dv.RowFilter = "code = " & id
    Else
MessageBox.Show("Error: ........")

End If

Dim strFilter As String = "code = " & id
dv.RowFilter = strFilter
```

but I can not filter a double value.

I actually use this code to filter strings in my DataGridView

```
  Private Sub MyTabDataGridView_DoubleClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyTabDataGridView.DoubleClick

        Try

            'MyRow
            Dim row As Integer = MyTabDataGridView.CurrentRow.Index
            'MyColumn
            Dim column As Integer = MyTabDataGridView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex
            'MyColumn and MyRow
            Dim ColumnRow As String = MyTabDataGridView(column, row).FormattedValue.ToString

            'Header Text
            Dim HeaderText As String = MyTabDataGridView.Columns(column).HeaderText

            'I exclude the errors
            If HeaderText = "id" Or HeaderText = "MyCol3" Or HeaderText = "MyCol4" Or HeaderText = "MyCol5" Then

                Exit Sub

            End If

            'Ready to filter
            Dim strFilter As String = HeaderText & " Like '*" & ColomnRow.Replace("'", "''") & "*'"
            dv.RowFilter = strFilter

        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
```

Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Solution:

Private Sub MyTabDataGridView_DoubleClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyTabDataGridView.DoubleClick

```
    Try
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US")

        'MyRow
        Dim row As Integer = MyTabDataGridView.CurrentRow.Index
        'MyColumn
        Dim column As Integer = MyTabDataGridView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex
        'MyColumn and MyRow
        Dim ColumnRow As String = MyTabDataGridView(column, row).FormattedValue.ToString

        'Header Text
        Dim HeaderText As String = MyTabDataGridView.Columns(column).HeaderText

        'I exclude the errors
        If HeaderText = "id" Then

            Exit Sub

        End If

        If HeaderText = "MyCol1" Or HeaderText = "MyCol2" Then

            'Si filtra
            Dim strFilter As String = HeaderText & " Like '*" & ColumnRow & "*'"
            dv.RowFilter = strFilter

        ElseIf HeaderText = "MyCol3" Or HeaderText = "MyCol4" Or HeaderText = "MyCol5" Then

            Dim strFilter2 As String = HeaderText & "= " & ColumnRow.Replace(",", ".")
            dv.RowFilter = strFilter2

        End If

        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("it-IT")

        'Refresh il DataGridView
        Me.MyTabDataGridView.Refresh()

    Catch ex As Exception

        Dim lNewVariable2 As String = "mailto:myadd@libero.it?subject=Invio Dati " & "&body= {0}{1}{2}"
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(String.Format(lNewVariable2, ex.Message, Environment.NewLine, ex.StackTrace))

    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: The code to filter double values should be much the same as the code you use for Integer, but using `Double.TryParse`.

Comment: I tried Double.TryParse but with no success. The data to be filtered is not in a correct format. How to convert before filtering?

Comment: This looks more like VB.NET, not VBA.

Comment: [Make TryParse compatible with comma or dot decimal separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29452263/make-tryparse-compatible-with-comma-or-dot-decimal-separator) may help. Also, for the currency Access type, you probably want Decimal.TryParse rather the Double version.

Comment: The column data is Double and NOT Integer. If I filter with Like it returns "Impossible to execute the operation 'Like' on System.Double and System.String". If I use = (normally for Integers) it doesn't work because the column data is Double. Of course if I click on 70,00 it works! (Integer)...but if I click on 70,58 it doesn't work.

Comment: I found a solution.             System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US")
            Dim strFilter As String = "MyCol3 = " & ColumnRow.Replace(",", ".") 
            dv.RowFilter = strFilter Thank you all for the help

Comment: Thanks to Andrew Morton. The solution arose from his hint. This solution is working whether you are aware that the column data is Double so to avoid the TryParse that I haven't checked yet.

Comment: If you're issue is resolved then please post an answer and, if you're able to, accept it, so that we can see that the issue is resolved without having to read the question and all the comments.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make TryParse compatible with comma or dot decimal separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29452263/make-tryparse-compatible-with-comma-or-dot-decimal-separator)