# NumberFormatInfo NumberDecimalDigits not working(?)

Tags: c#

I'm trying to get string interpretation of double value with dot as separator and two decimal digits but:

```
double d = 8.78595469;
Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("F"));
```

Returns `8,78`

So I was trying to use [NumberFormatInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) class according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3135569/how-to-change-symbol-for-decimal-point-in-double-tostring) question:

```
double d = 8.78595469;

var formatInfo = new NumberFormatInfo
{
    NumberDecimalSeparator = ".",
    NumberDecimalDigits = 2
};

Console.WriteLine(d.ToString(formatInfo));
```

Returns `8.78595469`, well separator is dot just what i wanted but why there is more than 2 decimal digits?

**EDIT:**

I'm not searching for other way to achieve this (I can use `.ToString("0.00", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` but I'm wondering why `NumberDecimalDigits` is not working(?)

Comment: d.ToString("F", formatInfo) ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want to use NumberFormatInfo, then you have to use the N Format specifier.

```
double d = 8.78595469;

var formatInfo = new NumberFormatInfo
{
    NumberDecimalSeparator = ".",
    NumberDecimalDigits = 2
};

Console.WriteLine(string.Format(formatInfo, "{0:N}", d)); <--- N specifier
```