# NumberFormatInfo NumberDecimalDigits not working despite similar answer

Tags: c#, string, type-conversion, double, data-conversion

This seems a pretty simple task but I can't get this sort out.
I need to write a decimal number on whatever international system with

1. no thousand separator '
2. decimal separator as .
3. a fixed number of decimals

**So no 1'234,56789 but 1234.5678**

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43850022/numberformatinfo-numberdecimaldigits-not-working) answer it seems pretty simple.

I have define

```
var nfi = new NumberFormatInfo()
{
    NumberDecimalSeparator = ".",
    PerMilleSymbol = "",
    NumberDecimalDigits = 4
};
```

and then I use it with

```
string aaa = string.Format(nfi, "{0:N}", d);
```

or

```
string aaa = d.ToString("N", nfi);
```

but with that the thousand separator is not working for I get "1,234.5679"

Instead if I do

```
string aaa = d.ToString(nfi);
```

it is the NumberDecimalDigits not working for I get "1234.56789000003"

So in both ways I can't all the constraints to get working.

Thanks for helping me to find the clean way to solve this.
Patrick

Comment: Standard approach would be to use builtin `InvariantCulture`, literally culture independent formatting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Are using  `PerMilleSymbol` when the correct one is `NumberGroupSeparator`

so your custom format info should be

```
var nfi = new NumberFormatInfo()
{
    NumberDecimalSeparator = ".",
    NumberGroupSeparator= "",
    NumberDecimalDigits = 4
};
```

Comment: Thanks! And with that the correct usage is string aaa = string.Format(nfi, "{0:N}", d);