# How to use NumberFormatInfo

Tags: c#, formatting, double

I want to be able to format any decimal number as I want.
Specifically I want to be able to control:

1. the number of decimals
2. the decimal separator
3. the thousand separator

I have tried to do that

```
var nfi = new NumberFormatInfo();
nfi.NumberDecimalDigits= 4;       <----- for point 1
nfi.NumberDecimalSeparator = "@"; <----- for point 2
nfi.NumberGroupSeparator = "^";   <----- for point 3? or
nfi.PerMilleSymbol= "#";          <----- for point 3?
```

and then I have applied it:

[image]

but for some reasons I can't get to have what I expect.

If I look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimaldigits?view=net-8.0#system-globalization-numberformatinfo-numberdecimaldigits) it seems that it applies to integers?

And also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77408548/numberformatinfo-numberdecimaldigits-not-working-despite-similar-answer?rq=2) is not helping.

Comment: What is the desired result, please? Note, that `aaa.ToString(nfi);` is actually `aaa.ToString("g", nfi);` and `"g"` - **general** - *format string* doesn't use group separator and `NumberDecimalDigits` let alone `PerMillSymbol`. You can try `aaa.ToString("f", nfi);` with `"f"` - float - format string to use `NumberDecimalDigits`

Comment: Ok your comment might be my answer. So nfi alone can't do everything. I thought that it could COMPLETELY format any number. So it has to be used in conjunction with ("N4",nfi) if I want to define the number of decimals. So .numberOfDecimalDigits is useless. Thanks! You might want to post it as an answer

Comment: @DmitryBychenko - seems like my answer crossed paths with yours.  Should I delete?

Comment: @dbc: No, please, keep your answer: it's a better one (more details, better formatted, references to manual), I've dropped my.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formatting properties `NumberDecimalDigits`, `NumberDecimalSeparator`, `NumberGroupSeparator` and `PerMilleSymbol` do not apply to all [format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings).  To  determine their applicability you need to check the docs:

- [`NumberDecimalDigits`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimaldigits?view=net-8.0#remarks): *The NumberDecimalDigits property is used with the "F" and "N" standard format strings without a precision specifier in numeric formatting operations.*
- [`NumberDecimalSeparator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimalseparator?view=net-8.0#remarks): *The NumberDecimalSeparator property is used with the "E", "F", "G", "N", and "R" standard format strings to define the symbol that separates integral from fractional digits.*

  It also used by the ["." custom specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings#the--custom-specifier-1).
- [`NumberGroupSeparator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numbergroupseparator?view=net-8.0#remarks): *The NumberGroupSeparator property is used with the "N" standard format string to define the symbol that separates groups of integral digits.*

  It is also used by the ["," custom specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings#the--custom-specifier-2).
- [`PerMilleSymbol`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.permillesymbol?view=net-8.0#remarks): *The string assigned to the PerMilleSymbol property is included in the result string when a numeric value is formatted with a format string that includes the "‰" .*

Since, as noted in the [doc remarks for `ToString(IFormatProvider)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tostring?view=net-8.0#system-double-tostring(system-iformatprovider)):

> The ToString(IFormatProvider) method formats a Double value in the default ("G", or general) format of a specified culture.

Only `NumberDecimalSeparator` applies in this format.  You need to pass formats for which you the other options are implemented to see their effect.  For instance:

```
double aaa = -123456.789;
foreach (var formatString in new [] { "G", "N", "F", "P", "#0.## " + '\u2030'})
{
    string str = aaa.ToString(formatString, nfi);
    Console.WriteLine("aaa.ToString(\"{0}\", nfi) = {1}", formatString, str);
}
```

Results in:

```
aaa.ToString("G", nfi) = -123456@789
aaa.ToString("N", nfi) = -123^456@7890
aaa.ToString("F", nfi) = -123456@7890
aaa.ToString("P", nfi) = -12,345,678.90 %
aaa.ToString("#0.## ‰", nfi) = -123456789 #
```

Demo fiddle here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/81HXz9