# Changing the decimal separator in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Is there a setting to change the default decimal separator `(',' to '.')` for `float/double/decimal` in `VC 2017`?

Right now i have to copy-paste this into every project:

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo customCulture = (System.Globalization.CultureInfo)System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone();
customCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = customCulture;
```

EDIT: Okay, figured this one out thanks to Tim. This setting is OS based, therefore you have to change it in your OS settings.

For Windows you have to type "Region" into the Search box. Go to Additional Settings and change the "Decimal symbol" option.

Comment: You want to change VS behavior or in your app?

Comment: VS behavior. Thought it would be somewhere in Tools --> Options, but i can't find it in there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change symbol for decimal point in double.ToString()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3135569/how-to-change-symbol-for-decimal-point-in-double-tostring)