# Useless substitutions when converting from decimal to string

Tags: c#

Good morning,

if I convert a Decimal variable to String it replaces "." with "," is it possible to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Have you read the documentation? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.tostring?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change symbol for decimal point in double.ToString()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3135569/how-to-change-symbol-for-decimal-point-in-double-tostring)

Comment: " it replaces "." with "," " that depends on the culture of your machine if you haven't specified it explicitly inside your code. That means that the conversion can lead to different results when your code runs on a different machine

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are hitting a culture formatting issue. The Microsoft documentation for Decimal.ToString() has the solution you need, but for quickness you can use:

```
value.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

or replace CultureInfo.InvariantCulture with

```
CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("insert culture short code")
```

Comment: it is not possible to do it globally without having to specify it to each string?

Comment: @FrancescoBuscicchio - yes it is. Now you need to look into Globalization in the web.config. That's a whole topic in itself, so enjoy all the reading. Best way to learn ;-)

Comment: @ColinWiseman :D it is difficult to avoid devloping into a word picker over time here. I'll delete my comment ;)