# Is there a way to format a float with a colon instead of a period?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to convert a float (which represents a small time period between `0.000` and `3.000` seconds) into a string in the format `00:000`, where all leading zeros remain.

Using `(float).ToString("00.000").Replace(".",":")` works, but it feels like there's a "better" way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change symbol for decimal point in double.ToString()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3135569/how-to-change-symbol-for-decimal-point-in-double-tostring)

Comment: Sadly not, as I don't know what "culture" uses this format (if any). I would assume that using `nfi.NumberDecimalSeparator = ":"` then `(float).ToString("00.000", nfi)` would work, but the decimal point remains. Using `(float).ToString(nfi)`, doesn't take into account the `00:000` formatting I want either. @FranzGleichmann

Comment: Fractional seconds are normally separated from the whole number of seconds by the culture's decimal separator - usually either `,` or `.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[float.ToString()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.single.tostring?view=net-6.0#system-single-tostring(system-string-system-iformatprovider)) has an overload that takes both a format *and* a formatprovider.

In combination, you can have both your leading and trailing zeroes and `:` as separator:

```cs
using System;
using System.Globalization;


public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        float input = 3.14156F;
        string format = "00.000";
        
        var nfi = new NumberFormatInfo();
        nfi.NumberDecimalSeparator = ":";
        
        string output = input.ToString(format, nfi);
        
        Console.WriteLine(output);
    }
}
```

[output: `03:142`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/m8NBLP)